# Good examples for multiprocessing with pySerial

Tags: python, multiprocessing, arduino, pyserial

Is there any place where I can have a look at examples which perform [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial.html#overview) operations in a multiprocessing environment in Python?

===Update to the above question ===

Code for Arduino:

```
//Initialize the pins

void setup()
{
    //Start serial communication
}

void loop()
{
    //Keep polling to see if any input is present at the serial PORT
    //If present perform the action specified.
    //In my case : TURN ON the led or TURN OFF.
}
```

Similarly code for the Python front-end:

For basic reference I used *[Painless Concurrency: The multiprocessing Module](http://revista.python.org.ar/1/html-en/PET-1-processing.pdf)*,  (PDF, 3.0 MB).

```
#import the different modules like time,multiprocessing
#Define the two parallel processes:
def f1(sequence):
    #open the serial port and perform the task of controlling the led's
    #As mentioned in the answer to the above question : Turn ON or OFF as required
    #The 10 seconds ON, then the 10 seconds OFF,finally the 10 seconds ON.

def f2(sequence):
    #Perform the task of turning the LED's off every 2 seconds as mentioned.
    #To do this copy the present conditions of the led.
    #Turn off the led.
    #Turn it back to the saved condition.

def main():
    print "Starting main program"

    hilo1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f1, args=(sequence))
    hilo2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f2, args=(sequence))

    print "Launching threads"
    hilo1.start()
    hilo2.start()
    hilo1.join()
    hilo2.join()
    print "Done"

if ____name____ == '____main____':
    main()
```

There are a few issues I am facing on performing the above:

1. Process f1 performs the task as required. That is to turn on the LED for 10 seconds, turn off the LED for 10 seconds, and finally turn on the LED for 10 seconds. By the look of it, it looks like the process f2 does not get executed (that is, there is no turning OFF of the LED every two seconds) at all though the program ends successfully. What could be happening here?
2. If I use print to print something in the processes, it does not appear on the screen. I am curious to know as to how the people mentioning the examples were able to display the output of the prints of the processes.

Comment: pyserial has its own internal blocking calls to `select`. One of the main reasons I don't use it. It's hard to integrate it into larger software system.

Comment: @Keith : Then what package do you use to make serial connections calls?

Comment: I use [my own package](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/), and the [tty.py](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/aid/pycopia/tty.py#562) module there.  It's simpler but effective, and can be combined with the [asyncio.py](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/core/pycopia/asyncio.py) module to multiplex input in a reactor model.

Answer (score 0):

why have you used join ? join blocks the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs. 
Thats why your f2 isn't starting because f1 is running.

try this code in main instead

```
procs = []
procs.append(Process(target=f1, args=(sequence))
procs.append(Process(target=f2, args=(sequence))
map(lambda x: x.start(), procs)
map(lambda x: x.join(), procs)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/07/a-live-data-monitor-with-python-pyqt-and-pyserial/) you have a code sample of PySerial monitoring in a GUI app (PyQt), running in a separate thread.

Comment: I was actually looking at controlling a set of LED's connected to the Arduino board. I wanted most of my processing to be done on the python end. There are 2 tasks i have to perform at the same time.
a) Process1 : Control a set of led's based on a certain pattern of input.(say the pattern is :: turn on the LED for 10 seconds, then turn off for 10 seconds . then again turn on for 10 seconds )
b) Process2 : Turn off the led's at certain instances of time (say every 2 seconds).

Comment: In layman terms - This whole thing will perform the operation **similar** to sampling the light . Is the multiprocessing the right direction i am looking at ? Kindly suggest .

Comment: @Abhishek: well, you have an example now. Good luck with your task - and if you run into specific problems, feel free to ask additional questions

Comment: @Abhishek: do note that only a single process (in the OS sense) can open a given serial port at the same time. What you specify here can be easily done within a single thread with the help of time keeping

Comment: @Abhishek It sounds like you want to do event driven programming, e.g. "In 10 seconds time, toggle LED 2". This is pretty easy with [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

Comment: @jozzas: only if twisted supports pyserial though, because it's blocking

Comment: @jozzoa : I was just about to ask something similar to Eli. Does it support serial port communication ??

Comment: @Eli : I have gone ahead and written small codes to do the task as mentioned. But there are issues as expected. Kindly suggest where i am going wrong.

Comment: @Abhishek: what is the question? - perhaps you should open a separate SO question for it

Comment: @Eli : Sorry is there some mistake i have made while asking the questions?

Comment: @Abhishek: yes. You start by asking for an example. When received an answer, you ask different questions in the comments about your desired scheme. When that is answered, you dump a huge load of code into the original question, asking us to debug it. This is not how SO works, and it is now how one should ask questions if one expects to be taken seriously

Comment: @:Eli : Thank you for the reference to the "How to as questions the smart way". I hope i have done the right thing now?

Comment: @Eli Twisted can make blocking calls in a separate thread, see the docs for [callInThread](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html#auto1)